# Mobx change in observable object doesn`t trigger change in component render

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mobx

I`m work on React+Mobx+Firebase app.

From firebase I subscribe to datatabase.ref.on('value') listener, and on any db update receive an object with structure like this:

```
user:{
    name:'UserName'
    project:{
        pages:{
            1:{
                section:{
                    style:{
                       width:'100%'
                    }
                }
             }
          }
     }
}
```

Now - for example - if I make a direct change in firebase console in user.name field - my component is updated at the same time,
but if I want to make any change in deeper level props, like style - component is not updated

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please include your code. It works [**for me**](http://jsbin.com/cabogulawo/1/edit?js,console,output). Change `user.project.pages['1'].section.style.width` in the console and the component will update.